# Where is generated items (products) table in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

I've looked around on Google and the WooCommerce docs, but I feel like I'm not using the correct terminology here. Hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction.

I need to add a column to the cart table (not sure what it's actually called) that is populated on checkout pages, for example on the checkout/order-pay/ endpoint.

You can see an example here:

[image]

I've looked in various templates for the order, review-order, checkout, etc, but to no avail. Where is this table generated in the source code? I assume that it's part of some kind of array that gets looped through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is related to **Pay Order page** (see below):

- On **cart** page, cart items table is generated on [`cart/cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/cart/cart.php) template file.
- On **mini cart**, cart items table is generated on [`cart/mini-cart.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/cart/mini-cart.php) template file.
- On **Pay Order** page, the products table is generated on [**`checkout/form-pay.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/checkout/form-pay.php) template file.
- On **checkout** page, the products table is generated on [`checkout/review-order.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/checkout/review-order.php) template file.
- On **Order received** *(Thankyou)* and **My account > orders > view order** pages, the products table is generated on [`order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/order/order-details.php) and [`order/order-details-item.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/order/order-details-item.php) template files.
- On **Email notifications**, the products table is generated on [`emails/email-order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/emails/email-order-details.php) and [`emails/email-order-items.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/templates/emails/email-order-items.php) template files.